# How to make 2 subfigures to take up whole width in 2 column document without minipage, float

Tags: floats, subfloats

I would like to put a figure with 2 subfigures at the top of the same page that they are included in the code. The document is in 2 column format, but I want the figure to take up both columns (placed horizontally, ignoring columns, rather than vertically -- see below).

Per submission guidelines, I can't use the float or minipage packages.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Just a guess, but do you have a blank line between the two subfigures?  Or forgot the \hfil between them?